# How to use view's relationships to pull user entity reference data?

Tags: 7, views, users

I created 2 new user fields for the user (object/entity) on my D7 site. Using views, I can select 'content' or 'user' for querying data. When I use views to query the 'user', the 2 new fields come up just fine. However, when I select 'content', the 2 new fields are not there. This makes sense to me since the 2 new fields are tied to the user entity.

For my purposes, I need both content AND user data. The strange or weird thing is, when I select 'content' for my base and use relationships to find and pull user entity fields, SOME old custom created fields already tied to the User Entity is present and I can select them, BUT my 2 new fields are not.

I tried clearing caches and making sure I had active content with the 2 new fields enabled. So why can I find in relationships, entity references to old custom fields, but not my new fields I created?

It feels like a catch 22. If I select user, I have my new fields, but not the content, and vice versa.

Comment: If you're starting with user view, add relationship of author content. 
If you're starting with content view and relationship of author.
How did you got about creating these 2 new user fields? Did you do it through the UI? OR did you do it programmatically via custom module?

Comment: I set the data through the field UI. I added author content like you said and now I can use the 2 new fields in my tables view. The field values are boolean and it doesn't display true or false, but I think I just have to mess with it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Relationship that introduces "backwards" Entity reference info into the Views.

In Drupal 7 that is called something like this (you can find this in the list of Relationships in your Content Views under the `Entity Reference` Category):

> **Entity Reference: Referencing entity**
>   A bridge to the User entity that is referencing Content via field_[myERfield]

After you have that you will be able to add the `User: Name` field, it will automatically use the above Relationship, and it will show which user referenced that particular node, for your each Views row.

---

In Drupal 8 the Relationship is called

> **User using field_[myERfield]**
>   Relate each User with a field_[myERfield] set to the content.

The procedure is the same, you can now add Fields or Filters relating to User fields/data, if they're set to use the Relationship the user shown will be the one referencing the content of that Views row.